# Threading.Timer application is consuming more than 50% of CPU, why?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, console-application, visual-studio-2003, timertask

I have written below console application in VB.net.

My intention is to write an application that triggers every one minute and perform some task. But

when I run this application it is consuming 50% of CPU.

How can I make it to consume less CPU?

Am I calling the timer in the right place (In the main method)?

Later I would like to make a windows service with this same task and install on the server.

How can I make the application consume less CPU?

```
Module Module1

    Dim inputPath As String = "C:\Input"
    Dim outputPath As String = "C:\Output"
    Dim folder As Directory

    Sub Main()
        Dim tmr As Timer = New Timer(New TimerCallback(AddressOf Upload), Nothing, 1000, 60000)
        While Not tmr Is Nothing
        End While

    End Sub

    Public Sub Upload(ByVal o As Object)
        Dim sr As StreamReader
        Dim conStr1 As String = "Data Source=TNS Name;User ID=xx; Password=xx;"
        'Look up for pending requests in RQST_TBL
        Dim cnn1 As New OracleConnection(conStr1)
        Dim datReader As OracleDataReader
        Dim cmd1 As New OracleCommand
        cnn1.Open()
        .....
        .....
    End Sub

End Module
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have two CPUs?  The infinite while loop is consuming 100% of one CPU; leaving you with 50% total CPU consumption.

From the look of your code - the loop is completely unneeded.  Your timer class is going to call the Upload() method when it is complete.

Remove the while loop...

```
While Not tmr Is Nothing 
End While
```

And use something like Console.Readline to keep the application from closing.

Alternatively stick a thread.sleep() call inside the while loop if you really like the loop.

Comment: Thank you. I did this and it gives no load to CPU.

Answer (score 2):

```
While Not tmr Is Nothing
End While
```

You were already warned about this in a previous question.  Delete that code.

Comment: I have added Thread.Sleep(60000) in the while loop and it is taking almost 0% of CPU. Thank you so much. Sorry about that that I missed previous warning..

Answer (score 2):

```
While Not tmr Is Nothing
End While
```

This is just an infinite loop. You're not actually allowing anything to get done.

As this is a console application, you probably only need a loop that sleeps for a minute, then performs your task.

Answer (score 1):

As Rob said, the 50% load probably means you're using 100% of one of your CPUs cores.

Instead of the infinite loop, you can use `Console.ReadLine()` to keep the console application running.

While the console is waiting for input, your timer will still work as you intend it.